# Getting NHibernate.Bytecode.ProxyFactoryFactoryNotConfiguredException

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm new to NHibernate and trying to set it up on Visual Studio 2013. I'm mostly done with the setup but it keeps throwing the error in the title during the debug.
I have been here:
[Summer of Nhibernate Session 01, why am I getting NHibernate.Bytecode.ProxyFactoryFactoryNotConfiguredException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633555/summer-of-nhibernate-session-01-why-am-i-getting-nhibernate-bytecode-proxyfacto)

Only problem it's doesn't help me much as Castle.Core doesn't work with the latest NHibernate 3.3. Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate 3.x and above has its own internal ProxyFactory.  You don't need to set this up anymore.

Here's a more recent quick tutorial on how to setup NHibernate.  http://www.dotnetjalps.com/2013/09/asp-net-mvc-nhibernate-crud-getting-started.html

I don't like how it's doing session management, but this will at least get you started.

Also NHibernate is currently at 4.x, why are you using 3.3 or think that it is the current version.

I'd recommend taking a look at https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/nhibernate-30-cookbook.  It's a good NHibernate resource.

Also check out http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/02/nhibernates-mapping-by-code-summary.html

It's a great summary for mapping by code.

Comment: I got NHibernate from nhforge and it seems like they stopped updating it. I just updated the version of nhibernate in my project and it is now working

Comment: Get nhibernate using its night package.